# explain the USING command

Tags: mysql, join, using

Take a look...

http://search.mysql.com/search?site=refman-41&q=using&lr=lang_en

The official MySQL site doesn't explain the USING command.

Can you do that please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USING is a variation of the ON keyword in join syntax. [This link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0100__Table-Join/ThekeywordUSINGcanbeusedasareplacementfortheONkeywordduringthetableJoins.htm) explains it in detail. In the example, the query

```
SELECT C.First_Name, C.Last_Name, O.title
FROM Employee AS C
LEFT JOIN job as O USING (ID);
```

is identical to

```
SELECT C.First_Name, C.Last_Name, O.title
FROM Employee AS C
LEFT JOIN job as O ON C.ID = O.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's used for JOINs:

[MySQL: 12.2.8.1. JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

"The USING(column_list) clause names a list of columns that must exist in both tables. If tables a and b both contain columns c1, c2, and c3, the following join compares corresponding columns from the two tables."

Answer (score 0):

It is used in JOINs, I think you can get [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0100__Table-Join/0200__USING.htm) some more information about it.